# WPF Navigation of the main page not affected by a frame

Tags: wpf, browser, navigation

I am having an issue where I have a page that has a frame on it and the frame is set to several different pages itself as the main page is being used. When I go to hit the back button to navivate the main page back to the previous page, I have to have my frame go back through every page it's navigated to first, and then it will back up the main page. All I'm using to go back is the standard:

```
    this.NavigationService.GoBack();
```

Is there a way to keep my frame from adding pages to my Navigational Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not very clear but this may be what you are looking for.

```
Frame Source="FramePage1.xaml" JournalOwnership="OwnsJournal"
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed! Sorry for the rough wording on the question but I didn't want to get over wordy and I didn't know exactly how to say it.